# Many embedded Mono in a single application

Tags: c++, mono

Is possible to put many different Mono Runtime in the same application?
I successfully embed Mono into my application but wanna start many different Mono Runtime and when I try, it raise an exception.
The reason why I need different runtimes instead of different AppDomain is because I need to run every application into a different working directory

```
void newEnvironment(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MonoDomain *m_pRootDomain;
    MonoImage *m_pClassLibraryImage;

    MonoClass *m_pClassLibraryManagerClass;
    MonoObject *m_pClassLibraryManager;

    mono_debug_init(MONO_DEBUG_FORMAT_MONO);

    mono_set_dirs(PathUtil::GetLibDirectory().c_str(), PathUtil::GetConfigDirectory().c_str());

    m_pRootDomain = mono_jit_init_version("MonoApplication", "v4.0.30319");

    MonoAssembly *pMonoAssembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(m_pRootDomain, PathUtil::GetBinDirectory().append("ClassLibrary.exe").c_str());

    mono_jit_exec(m_pRootDomain, pMonoAssembly, argc, argv);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Required for mdb's to load for detailed stack traces etc.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::thread t1(newEnvironment, argc, argv);
    }
    char name[256];
    std::cin.getline(name, 256);
}
```

Comment: It is probably not possible, I imagine that *Mono* has some *global* state.